# How to access domain properties from a controller in Grails?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, controller, dns

I have the following Grails domain class:

```
class Product {  
    String name  
    Float basePrice  
    Category category  
    String image = "default.jpg"  

    static constraints = {
        name(size:3..25, blank:false)
        basePrice(scale:2, nullable:false)
        category(inList:Category.list(), nullable:false)
        image(blank:false)
    }
}
```

From a controller, I want to get the default value for the image property (in this case "default.jpg"). Something like this:

```
def productInstance = new Product(params)
productInstance.image = getProductPicturePath() ?: Product().image
```

getProductPicturePath returns an image path, but in case no image was submitted, the controller shall replace the null value with the default. While I could certainly write something like this:

```
productInstance.image = getProductPicturePath() ?: "default.jpg"
```

It's certainly not very DRY, and I would prefer to keep that default value in one place. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious solution is to declare it as a constant and then refer to it.

```
class Product {  
    static DEFAULT_IMAGE = "default.jpg"
    String name  
    Float basePrice  
    Category category  
    String image = DEFAULT_IMAGE

    static constraints = {
        name(size:3..25, blank:false)
        basePrice(scale:2, nullable:false)
        category(inList:Category.list(), nullable:false)
        image(blank:false)
    }
}

productInstance.image = getProductPicturePath() ?: Product.DEFAULT_IMAGE
```

Even better, make `getProductPicturePath()` return the default value.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `image` key in `params`

```
def productInstance = new Product(params)
```

will skip this property and leave the default value defined in the domain class. So, assuming that your params doesn't contain an `image` key, the simplest way would be to skip the assignment of the `image` property at all for those products that have no image:

```
def imagePath = getProductPicturePath()
if(imagePath) {
    productInstance.image = imagePath
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of that. My params contains an image key, it comes from a upload form with other fields and the user may or may not upload an image file.